# Angularjs Using Same Directive Multiple Times as Element Execution order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive multiple times as a element in a view.

the execution of this directives is not starts from the parent. it first executes the children directives and then parent. so when parent executes at last, by compiling it the childs are getting executed two times.

Code as follows:

```
<custom-directive dir-type="1">
   <custom-directive dir-type="2"></custom-directive>
   <custom-directive dir-type="3"></custom-directive>
   <custom-directive dir-type="4"></custom-directive>
</custom-directive>
```

Here the Type 1 Directive comes to execution after all childs execution completed. so when parent directive type 1 executes i'm compiling it custom html (say uib-set). so these child directives also again compiling.

So please Help me How can i execute parent directive first then childs next...

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt look very pretty, but it can easily be solved by using:

```
<custom-directive dir-type="1" ng-init="myTurn = true">
   <custom-directive dir-type="2" ng-if="myTurn"></custom-directive>
   <custom-directive dir-type="3" ng-if="myTurn"></custom-directive>
   <custom-directive dir-type="4" ng-if="myTurn"></custom-directive>
</custom-directive>
```

Now the child directives will be triggered/compiled *after* the parent is compiled and ready.

---

However, I think this can be solved by using `transclusion`.

Maybe you can try adding this to your directive:

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        //
        transclude: true,
        // 
    }
});
```

By using transclusion, you are 'telling' the parent element: "Hey, you have child elements". So Angular knows that the children belong to the parent, and they will (I think) wait for the parent element to be compiled.

*If this transclusion works, please do not use the first solution. It's best to avoid ng-init: it makes debugging harder.*

[Documentation on transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)